# ASM 4 (Java Library) tutorials?

Tags: java, bytecode, bytecode-manipulation

I have recently been working with the Java library 'ASM', which is for modification of bytecode at runtime, in case people didn't know, and I have not been able to find a single tutorial on ASM 4. Except the official manual for ASM 4, which referenced ASM classes that didn't even exist.

I am wondering if anyone knows of any tutorials for the library, which cover basic to intermediate things, such as inserting some code into a method.

Comment: Asking for an "up to date" something is pretty much the definition of too localized.

Comment: Ah, I reworded it to make more sense now. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Have you tried looking for any?  http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/02/manipulating-java-class-files-with-asm.html

Comment: Google returns 16K results...

Comment: That's good for the very basics, but I wish to move on into harder and more useful things, which I'm having trouble finding tutorials for.

Answer (score 6):

What you want to do seems pretty basic (to me).  I'd be very surprised if it was not covered, with an example, in the user guide: https://asm.ow2.io/asm4-guide.pdf

There is lots of other documentation linked here: http://asm.ow2.org/

The ASM mailing list is also quite responsive if you ask:  http://mail.ow2.org/wws/info/asm

Comment: yep, see page 105 of the linked PDF

Comment: The PDF has been moved here: https://asm.ow2.io/asm4-guide.pdf AFAIK it is the same PDF as mentioned in the answer, but I can't be sure.

Comment: This link also provides a nice example of ASM: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2755722&seqNum=7